# Why Can I not Get D3 Force Directed Graph Link Labels to work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to add link label to a force directed graph with support for drag and drop nodes like this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411).  Using that example I was able to create my graph with modifications to meed my requirements.

I now want to add labels to the links.  I see this is a very common question here and I  have viewed many of the examples shown on StackOverflow, and have tried to implement several of them. However the ones I have viewed do not have the support for drag and drop nodes.  I am currently trying to use the example found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mfolnovic/6269308/5c017c0391a8e12db1fc573be3ef8a9bdcb5a117) as a template and have added the code that appears to create the link labels to my project but it still does not work.

Below is my code snippet for the link labels:

```
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
.data(json.links)
.enter().append("svg:line")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; })

//****I have added this code to create the link labels****

    vis.append("svg:defs")
    .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("id", String)
    .append("svg:path");
var path = vis.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
 .attr("id", function (d) { return d.source.index + "_" +d.target.index; })
.attr("class", function (d) { return "link " + d.linkName; })
.attr("line-end", function (d) { return "url(#" + d.linkName + ")"; });

var path_label = vis.append("svg:g").selectAll(".path_label")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:text")
.attr("class", "path_label")
.append("svg:textPath")
  .attr("startOffset", "50%")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
  .style("fill", "#000")
  .style("font-family", "Arial")
  .text(function (d) { return d.linkName; });
//****End of added code******
```

Thanks for any help or suggestion.  Just a little more info the code I have added, and am showing above, does not cause the graph to fail, it renders the graph with the node information and the link lines it just does not add the labels.

Comment: Please edit your title to ask a specific question rather than listing a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get this to work.  The working code is shown below for anyone who is looking for a force directed graph that supports drag and drop nodes with line labels

```
var json = {
"nodes": [
{ "name": "Fabby MONDESIR", "dob": "5.24.97","group": 1 },
{ "name": "ADNES D BRONSON", "dob": "5.24.97","group": 1 }

],
"links": [
   { "source": 0, "target": 1, "linkName": "FCC", "value": 8 },
   { "source": 0, "target": 2, "linkName": "Arr", "value": 10 }

]
}
var w = 1024,
h = 768

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

//Create a force layout and bind Nodes and Links
var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .gravity(.05)
    .distance(250)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([w, h])
    .start();

//draw lines for links between nodes
var link = vis.selectAll(".gLink")
.data(json.links)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "gLink")
          .append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke", "#ccc")
            .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
/*  .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });*/


var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart)
    .on("drag", dragmove)
    .on("dragend", dragend);

function dragstart(d, i) {
    force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
}

function dragmove(d, i) {
    d.px += d3.event.dx;
    d.py += d3.event.dy;
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    tick(); // this is the key to make it work together with updating both px,py,x,y on d !
}

function dragend(d, i) {
    d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
    tick();
    force.resume();
}

//draw the nodes
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .call(node_drag);
//place mug shots on the nodes
node.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
.attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
    // d is the node data, i is the index of the node
    return d.ImageUrl;
})
    .attr("x", "-8px")
    .attr("y", "-8px")
    .attr("width", "96px")
    .attr("height", "96px");

//Append text data for the nodes
node.append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("dx", 0)//offset to move node text off the picture
    .attr("dy", -10)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name });
node.append("svg:text")//this gives us a second text line under the picture
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("dx", 0)//offset to move node text off the picture
        .attr("dy", 100)
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .text(function (d) { return d.dob });

// Append text to Link lines
var linkText = vis.selectAll(".gLink")
    .data(json.links)
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        if (d.target.x > d.source.x) { return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2); }
        else { return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2); }
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        if (d.target.y > d.source.y) { return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2); }
        else { return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2); }
    })
    //.attr("fill", "red")
    .style("fill", "Red")
    .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) { return d.linkName });


force.on("tick", tick);

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    linkText
      .attr("x", function (d) {
          if (d.target.x > d.source.x) { return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2); }
          else { return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2); }
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
          if (d.target.y > d.source.y) { return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2); }
          else { return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2); }
      });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not really answering your particular question but providing just a link to another example.

[Here's](http://pkuderov.github.io/network-model/vis_main.html) my course work which I'd done ~1.5 years ago so I don't really remember details now. On [github main page](https://github.com/pkuderov/network-model) you can find hotkeys list for the network editor (or just type `Visualizer.test()` in console for ready example).

This editor provides select/add/remove of graph nodes, drag-n-drop etc - I think this's what you need. The whole part of the editor's source code that you may find useful is in [this file](https://github.com/pkuderov/network-model/blob/master/vis/visualizer.js).

I hope somehow it may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have made changes to the code I am working with the code shown below.

```
var json = {
"nodes": [
    { "name": "Fabby MONDESIR", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635099", "group": 1 },
    { "name": "ADNES D BRONSON", "dob": "5.24.97", "ImageUrl": "http://172.18.215.101/MugImageAsp/MUGImageASP.ASP?WCI=RetrieveImage&WCE=FD635098", "group": 1 }

],
"links": [
   { "source": 0, "target": 1, "linkName": "test", "value": 8 }

]
}
var w = 1024, h = 768;


var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width",   w).attr("height", h);

//Create a force layout and bind Nodes and Links
var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(json.nodes)
.links(json.links)
.gravity(.05)
.distance(250)
.charge(-100)
.size([w, h])
.start();

//draw lines for links between nodes
var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
.data(json.links)
.enter().append("svg:line")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });


var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("dragstart", dragstart)
.on("drag", dragmove)
.on("dragend", dragend);

function dragstart(d, i) {
force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
}

function dragmove(d, i) {
d.px += d3.event.dx;
d.py += d3.event.dy;
d.x += d3.event.dx;
d.y += d3.event.dy;
tick(); // this is the key to make it work together with updating both px,py,x,y on d !
}

function dragend(d, i) {
d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
tick();
force.resume();
}

//draw the nodes
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
.data(json.nodes)
.enter().append("svg:g")
.call(node_drag);
//place photos on the nodes
node.append("svg:image")
.attr("class", "circle")
.attr("class", "circle")
.attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
// d is the node data, i is the index of the node
return d.ImageUrl;
})
.attr("x", "-8px")
.attr("y", "-8px")
.attr("width", "96px")
.attr("height", "96px");

//Append text data for the nodes
node.append("svg:text")
.attr("class", "nodetext")
.attr("dx", 0)//offset to move node data off the picture
.attr("dy", -10)
.style("fill", "blue")
.text(function (d) { return d.name });
node.append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("dx", 0)//offset to move node data off the picture
    .attr("dy", 100)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .text(function (d) { return d.dob });

// Append text to Link lines
var linkText = vis.selectAll(".link")
.data(json.links)
.append("text")
.attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
.attr("x", function (d) {
if (d.target.x > d.source.x) { return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2); }
else { return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2); }
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
    if (d.target.y > d.source.y) { return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2); }
    else { return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2); }
})
.attr("fill", "Black")
.style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function (d) { return d.linkName });


force.on("tick", tick);

function tick() {
link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

}
```

The graph is being drawn but still no text is being appended to the link lines.  When I debug I can see the x y coordinates being pulled from the drawing and the linkName being pulled from the data I just can't figure out why the text is not being displayed.